# argument type mismatch in netbeans project while inserting to database

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, insert, phpmyadmin

i am creating a web page that allow admin to manage the menu item. for the delete part, it is success.. but there's error when i wish to insert a new menu.

i am using phpmyadmin as my database

i gt this error when i run my netbeans project

HTTP Status 500-

**type:** Exception report

**description:** The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception:** org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

**root cause:** java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

**full stack trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.handleSetProperty(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:672)
at org.apache.jsp.confirmadd_jsp._jspService(confirmadd_jsp.java:90)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

***managemenu.jsp***

```
<h3>Add new menu</h3>
<div>
<form method="post" action="confirmadd.jsp">
<table>
<tr><td>Food ID</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="food_id" placeholder="food ID"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Food Name</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="food_name" placeholder="food name"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Food Description</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="food_description" placeholder="food desc"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Food Price</td><td>: </td><td><input type="text" name="food_price" placeholder="food price"/></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```

***confirmadd.jsp***

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<jsp:useBean id="newmenu" class="restaurantBean.menu" scope="session"/>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Confirm Add Food</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><br><h1>Restaurant E-menu and Reservation System</h1><br><br>

 <a href="main.jsp">Home</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="managemenu.jsp">Manage Menu</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="updatestock.jsp">Update stock</a>

<div class="content">
    <h1>Confirm Food</h1>
    <jsp:setProperty name="newmenu" property="food_id" value='<%=request.getParameter("food_id")%>'/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="newmenu" property="food_name" value="<%=request.getParameter("food_name")%>"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="newmenu" property="food_description" value='<%=request.getParameter("food_description")%>'/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="newmenu" property="food_price" value='<%=request.getParameter("food_price")%>'/>

    <table id="form">
        <tr><th colspan="3">Food Details</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Food ID</td><td>:</td><td><jsp:getProperty name="newmenu" property="food_id"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Food Name</td><td>:</td><td><jsp:getProperty name="newmenu" property="food_name"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Food Description</td><td>:</td><td><jsp:getProperty name="newmenu" property="food_description"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Food Price</td><td>:</td><td>RM<jsp:getProperty name="newmenu" property="food_price"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="button" value="proceed" onclick="location.href='./addmenu'"/>
    <input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></td></tr>
    </table>

</div>
</div>
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/includes/footer.jsp" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***menu.java***

```
package restaurantBean;

public class menu {
private String food_description;
private String food_id;
private String food_name;
private double food_price;


public void setFood_description(String a){
    food_description=a;
}
public String getFood_description(){
    return food_description;
}
public void setFood_id(String b){
    food_id=b;
}
public String getFood_id(){
    return food_id;
}
 public void setFood_price(double c){
    food_price=c;
}
public double getFood_price(){
    return food_price;
}
 public void setFood_name(String d){
    food_name=d;
}
public String getFood_name(){
    return food_name;
}

}
```

***addmenu.java***

```
package restaurantPackages;

import restaurantBean.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(name = "addmenu", urlPatterns = {"/addmenu"})
public class addmenu extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

           HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        menu m=(menu) session.getAttribute("newmenu");


        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant";
        String username="root";
        String password="";
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

        Statement statement=con.createStatement();            
        //ResultSet result=statement.executeQuery("select food_id from food where food_name='"+m.getFood_name().trim()+"'");
        //int c = 0;
        //while(result.next()){
        //c=result.getInt(1);
        //}
        PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into food (food_id, food_name, food_description, food_price) values (?,?,?,?)");
        stmt.setString(1,m.getFood_id());
        stmt.setString(2,m.getFood_name());
        stmt.setString(3,m.getFood_description());
        stmt.setDouble(4,m.getFood_price());

        stmt.executeUpdate();


        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        menu food=new menu();
        session.setAttribute("food",food);
        RequestDispatcher dis=request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/addsuccess.jsp");
        dis.forward(request,response);
    }
    catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e){
          out.println("ClassNotFoundException:"+e.getMessage());
       }catch(SQLException e){
            out.println("SQLState:  " + e.getSQLState());
            out.println("Message:  " + e.getMessage());
            out.println("Vendor:  " + e.getErrorCode());
       }
    finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

***addsuccess.jsp***

```
<div class="content">

<tr><td>Successfully add food ID = ${food.food_id} from restaurant</td></tr>
<table id="form">
        <tr><th colspan="3">New Added Food Details</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Food ID</td><td>:</td><td>${food.food_id}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Food Name</td><td>:</td><td>${food.food_name}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Food Description</td><td>:</td><td>${food.food_description}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Food Price</td><td>:</td><td>${food.food_price}</td></tr>

    </table>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="Continue Manage Menu" onclick="location.href='managemenu.jsp'"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="View Menu" onclick="location.href='main.jsp'"/>    </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no full stack trace I am guessing that the problem is here:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="newmenu" property="food_price" value='<%=request.getParameter("food_price")%>'/>
```

the food_price field is a double and maybe price format on your web form cannot be converted to double (just for a sake of test change food_price type to String and see what happens). And copy more of your stack trace here, so it will be easier to identify the problem.

Comment: wao! it's really the problem! i success to add it after i changed all the 'double' into 'String'.. if i wan use Double.. what is the way? thanks for helping

Comment: make sure that you convert String to parsable Double format before you set property. For instance if you have monetary value as 45,35 then you should convert that to 45.35 (or, even better, story it as cents, etc. - 4535.0 to avoid rounding problems as much as possible)